# Accessing the classPath of a file in a Java Project

Tags: java

Please, I have a file saved in src/org/people/Files/salary.txt

and I wanted to Read this file. I realized it could be done this way in java:

```
private final static String FILEPATH = "src/org/people/Files/salary.txt";
URL filePath = server.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILEPATH);
System.out.println(filePath.getFile());
```

When I tried to print this out, I get the error:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.." the reason being that when I tried

> System.out.println(filePath),

I get a null value. I am wondering how could I get this path so that when I try to print out the filePath, I will get the real path?

Comment: `getResource(FILEPATH)` is returning null, which means that no file actually exists on that path.  Double check that you're using the correct path.

Comment: You don't really want the "classpath" as you try to print the simple "path" of a plain text file.

Comment: @Vulcan, A file does exist there. I added it there. I am not sure if the path starts from /src or ./src. This was why I decided to use the built in getClass() methods to know exactly how the path is arranged in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible answers one being that instead of using / you should use \\ (Which is really just '\' in java). Another being that you are trying to extract a file from a web based url. An alternate method would be to use a buffered reader which looks like this: 

    `BufferedReader br = new BufferedRead(new FileReader(FILEPATH));
    while((br.readLine()) != null) {
    //Do Something Here...
    }`

I Hope this helped :) Please feel free to ask another question if you feel its necessary.

P.S The filepath may be incorrect; meaning you have forgotten a pathname